# Rep capped at 195

Tags: bug

Just a bug report:

[image]

+1 instead of +10, day capped at 195.

Potential source of issue:

[image]

---

**Update:**

It happened again today (7-Oct-2016), rep capped at 210 despite two accepts, i.e., there are posts with no score due to cap error.

Answer (score 5):

This has come up before. See: [What if I hit the daily rep cap and THEN get downvoted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70158/what-if-i-hit-the-daily-rep-cap-and-then-get-downvoted)

For better or worse, that's just how the rep cap system works. Once you hit 200, further upvotes simply don't count - they're NOT held in reserve in case you get lose rep in some way.

So it all depends on the order of events. Once you went down to 195, if someone had upvoted you again before the day was over, then you would have gone back up to 200.

It's probably not fair, but it's also probably not going to get fixed. Sorry, you just weren't lucky that day.

Comment: Someone did upvote before the day ended and it was still stuck at 195. First image is that vote.

Comment: @ymb1 interesting, you might be right. It looks like there was one vote that should have brought it back up to 200, but didn't for some reason. I'll ask someone to take a look at it tomorrow.

Comment: @ymb1 oh, sorry. I completely spaced getting someone to look at this. If I don't respond sometime early next week, re-ping me here or in chat.